# Alpha numeric regex pattern matching

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I need a regex that matches the alphanumeric patterns except totally numeric ones.

```
asdfgesod valid
1asdndwdd valid
asd124asd valid
a2asd43bd valid
123346678 invalid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*$/i
```

Broken down:

`^[a-z0-9]*` - String starts with any number (including zero) of alphanumeric characters

`[a-z]` - String has an `a-z` character

`[a-z0-9]*$` - String ends with any number (including zero) of alphanumeric characters

Comment: As you can see the first four match and the fifth doesn't as intended: http://codepad.viper-7.com/HiTFio

Comment: I feel silly when the answer is that easy. I tried lot of ridiculous things. Thank you so much. You saved me from endless headaches.

Comment: @tuze You're welcome. Also don't include the `i` at the end if you don't want (uppercase) `A-Z` to be considered alpha characters.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to use modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Use in case of java `StringUtils.isNumeric(String value)` check if string contains only numbers.

BTW: if string matches regex: `"^\d*$"` this means that it contains only digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
/^(?![0-9]+$)[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

[See it](http://rubular.com/r/veeQz1KYDz)

`[a-z0-9]+$` ensures the string is made of only alphanumeric characters.

The negative lookahead `(?![0-9]+$)` ensures the string is not all numeric.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to first check if the string contains only digits, if not check rest of the string. The following regex would do that:

```
^(?![\d]+$)[a-z0-9]+$
```

See it in action here: http://regexr.com?2v8n5